# Some equations in $\mathbb F_{37}$

Tags: finite-groups, congruences

How to solve efficiently the equations:

1) $[17][b]=[21]$

2) $[17][b]=[1]$

in $\mathbb F_{37}$

Comment: First, write them in a nicer form: $$\begin{align}&17b=21\pmod{37}\\&17b=1\pmod{37}\end{align}$$ In fact, making sure you are doing arithmetic modulo$\;37\;$ you cand even drop the $\;\pmod{37}\;$ . Now, number (2) also solves (1), so you have to find $\;a\in \Bbb F_{37}\;$ s.t. $\;17a=1\pmod{37}\iff a=17^{-1}\pmod{37}\;$

Answer (score 1):

It's no different from usual algebra: if $a\ne0$,
$$
ax=b \iff x=a^{-1}b
$$
The only problem is to find $[17]^{-1}$, that is, an integer $r$ such that
$$
[17][r]=[1]
$$
This means
$$
17r+37s=1
$$
and you find $r$ and $s$ with the (reverse) Euclidean algorithm:
\begin{align}
\color{red}{37}&=\color{red}{17}\cdot 2+\color{red}{3}\\
\color{red}{17}&=\color{red}{3}\cdot 5+\color{red}{2}\\
\color{red}{3}&=\color{red}{2}\cdot 1+\color{red}{1}
\end{align}
so
$$
\color{red}{1}=\color{red}{3}-\color{red}{2}=
\color{red}{3}-\color{red}{17}+\color{red}{3}\cdot 5=
-\color{red}{17}+(\color{red}{37}-\color{red}{17}\cdot2)\cdot 6=
-13\cdot\color{red}{17}+6\cdot\color{red}{37}
$$
Thus $r=-13$ and $[17]^{-1}=[r]=[-13]=[24]$.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (doing arithmetic modulo $\;37\;$ all along):

$$\begin{align}&17=-20=(-4)\cdot5\\
&(-4)\cdot9=-36=1\implies (-4)^{-1}=9\\
&5\cdot15=75=1\implies ...\end{align}$$

Now finish the argument.